# Magento security patch issue

Tags: patches, security, magento-1.14

I scanned my site from the New Magento Security Tool available from magento partner portal.

The report showed me two Vulnerability issues

1) SSL TLS - `Your server supports TLSv1.0. Please update your configuration to discontinue TLSv1.0 support.`

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a server configuration issue.

Depending on where/how you are hosting, contact your hosting provider to disable TLS v1.0.

If you're responsible for the server yourself, it depends on your setup.
You might also be interested in this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/314858/how-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-with-openssl-and-apache